# Prove that this $\epsilon$-ball intersects $C$

Tags: general-topology

Let $C=\{(x,\ y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid x,\ y\in\mathbb{Q}\text{, and }|x|+|y|\le 1\}$

Prove that $C$ is not closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

**My attempt:**

To do this, I plan to show that $\displaystyle\left(\frac{1}{\pi},\ \frac{1}{\pi}\right)\in\overline{C}$.

Since $\displaystyle\left(\frac{1}{\pi},\ \frac{1}{\pi}\right)\notin C$, that would prove that $\overline{C}\ne C$.

Let $\displaystyle B((x_0,\ y_0),\ \epsilon)$ be an $\epsilon$-ball containing $\displaystyle\left(\frac{1}{\pi},\ \frac{1}{\pi}\right)$. How do I prove that this $\epsilon$-ball intersects $C$?

Answer (score 1):

The answer may depend on how much you know (or accept) the facts.

If you accept the following two facts, then the answer is easy.

> **Fact 1.** The decimal expansion of an irrational number never repeats or terminates. Say
>   $$
> \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{\pi} &= 0.31830988618379067153776752674502872406891929148091\dotsb \\
> &= 0.a_1a_2a_3a_4a_5\dotsb = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{10^n}
> \end{align*}
> $$
>
> **Fact 2. (Archimedean property)** For any real number $\epsilon>0$, there exists a natural number $N$ such that $\frac{1}{\epsilon}<N$.

Given a real number $\epsilon>0$, it suffices to find a rational number $q$ such that
$|\frac{1}{\pi}-q|<\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{2}}$. Then
$$
|(\tfrac{1}{\pi},\tfrac{1}{\pi})-(q,q)|=\sqrt{2(\tfrac{1}{\pi}-q)^2}=\sqrt{2}|\tfrac{1}{\pi}-q|<\epsilon
$$
so that $(q,q)$ is included in the $\epsilon$-ball centered at $(\tfrac{1}{\pi},\tfrac{1}{\pi})$.

Now let us find a rational number $q$ such that $|\frac{1}{\pi}-q|<\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{2}}$. By Fact 2, there exists a natural number $N$ such that $\frac{1}{\epsilon/\sqrt{2}}<N$.

By Fact 1, we can write the decimal expansion of $\frac{1}{\pi}=0.a_1a_2a_3a_4a_5\dotsb$. Set
$$
q = 0.a_1a_2a_3\dotsb a_N = \sum_{n=1}^N\frac{a_n}{10^n}
$$
Then we have
$$
|\tfrac{1}{\pi}-q|=\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{10^n}<\frac{1}{10^N}<\frac{1}{N}<\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{2}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest in this way: Because $(1/\pi,1/\pi)\in\{|x|+|y|<1\}$, and there exists a sequence $p_{n}\in{\bf{Q}}$ such that $p_{n}\rightarrow 1/\pi$, so we have eventually that $(p_{n},p_{n})\in C$, but the limit point $(1/\pi,1/\pi)\notin C$, so $C$ is not closed.

Answer (score 0):

By the definition of the reals we have

(i). $\Bbb R$ is order-dense in itself. That is, if $a,b\in \Bbb R$ with  $a<b,$ then the real interval $(a,b)$ is not empty.

(ii). $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R.$ That is, $J\cap \Bbb Q\ne \emptyset$ for every non-empty open real interval $J.$

So for every $n\in \Bbb N$ let $x_n$ be a rational member of the real interval $(\frac {1}{\pi}(1-2^{-n}),\frac {1}{\pi}).$  The ordered pair $p_n=(x_n,x_n)$ belongs to $C,$ and the sequence $(p_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ converges to $(\frac {1}{\pi},\frac {1}{\pi}),$ which is not in $C.$

Comment: The definition of $\Bbb R$ is not  trivial .  We can have $ S\supsetneqq \Bbb R$ on which all the basic rules of  $+, \times,$ and $<$ apply.   But $S$ will contain positive members that are  less than every positive member of $\Bbb R$. If $x$ is one of these, then  $J=\{y\in S: 0<y<x\}$ is not empty (E.g.  $x/2\in J$) but $J\cap \Bbb R$ is empty. The disadvantage of such an $S$ is that a Cauchy sequence in $\Bbb R$ may fail  to converge in $ S.$ For example, with $x_n$ as  in my answer, the sequence  $(x_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ is bounded and increasing but has no $glb$ in $S.$